# Passing current UITableViewCell swipe to parent UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, swift-protocols

I have a custom `UITableViewCell`, which has a functionality to be swiped to the right. The swipe gesture is based on the translation of x-axis, so, when the translation of x is exceeded 40 points, I want to trigger a segue.

I think this is a perfect place to use delegates to pass data about the current X value. So, I have created a `protocol` with a function `didSwipeCell()`, but I'm not sure how to pass the current x value to the `UITableView`.

Please let me know how to do it, and if you need any extra info, please let me know in the comment instead of downvoting.

Comment: Do you already have the swipe code working? Do you want to pass the actual X value? Or do you just want to send "didSwipeCell()" to the TableViewController?

Comment: Why not adding parameter to `didSwipeCell()` that include the `x` value?

Comment: @DonMag I already have the swipe code working, I just want to send the X value. I’m just intersect in passing the X value to the UITableViewController using delegates.

Comment: You can do it with a "Closure Callback" - which may be easier / more straight forward than using delegates. Can you post your Cell's code where you recognize the 40 points and you're ready to send "didSwipeCell()"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add x value as a parameter of didSwipeCell() method

```
protocol TableViewCellDelegate {
    func didSwipeCell(on xValue: Float)
}
```

Add the delegate instance to your cell

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?
}
```

Then, call the method when user swipes the cell giving xValue

```
delegate?.didSwipeCell(on: xValue)
```

In your UITableView implement TableViewCellDelegate method.

```
 class TableView: UITableView, TableViewCellDelegate {
     func didSwipeCell(on xValue: Float) {
         //here you can get the xValue
     }
```

And, do not forget to set the delegate of TableViewCell in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, that's exactly what I was looking for (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of x simply from your **UItableViewCell** Class to your **UIViewController**. Declare closure

```
var getValue: ((_ xValue: CGFloat)->())!
```

in your **UItableViewCell** Class and implement it into your **UIViewController** Class.

In ViewController

```
cell. getValue = { (xValue) in
// do what you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it...

```
class SwipeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var didSwipeAction : ((CGFloat)->())?
    var startLocation = CGPoint.zero
    var theSwipeGR: UISwipeGestureRecognizer?

    func respondToSwipeGesture(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipe = sender as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            if (swipe.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began) {
                startLocation = swipe.location(in: self.contentView);
            } else if (swipe.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended) {
                let stopLocation = swipe.location(in: self.contentView);
                let dx = stopLocation.x - startLocation.x;
                if dx > 40 {
                    // pass the ending X coordinate in the callback
                    didSwipeAction?(stopLocation.x)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        myInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        myInit()
    }


    func myInit() -> Void {
        if theSwipeGR == nil {
            let g = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture(_:)))
            g.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
            self.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(g)
            theSwipeGR = g
        }
    }

}
```

and then your table view cell setup becomes:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SwipeCell", for: indexPath) as! SwipeTableViewCell

    cell.didSwipeAction = {
        (xValue) in
        print("Simple", indexPath, "X =", xValue)
        // call performSegue() or do something else...
    }

    return cell
}
```